# HAProxy environment refusing to connect

Tags: haproxy

I have an installation with 2 webservices behind a load balancer with HAProxy. While on service run by 3 servers responds quite fine, the other service with just one server doesn't.

So basically here's what should happen:

loadbalancer --> rancherPlatformAdministration if certain url is used
loadbalancer --> rancherServices for all other requests

Here's my haproxy.cfg:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    # Define hosts
    acl host_rancherAdmin hdr(host) -i admin.mydomain.tech

    use_backend rancherPlatformAdministration if host_rancherAdmin
    default_backend rancherServices

backend rancherServices
    balance roundrobin
    server rancherserver91 192.168.20.91:8080 check
    server rancherserver92 192.168.20.92:8080 check
    server rancherserver93 192.168.20.93:8080 check

backend rancherPlatformAdministration
    server rancherapi01 192.168.20.20:8081 check
```

`wget --server-response foo.mydomain.tech` answers with a 401 which is respected behaviour as I am not providing a username nor a password. I can also open up `foo.mydomain.tech` with my browser an log in. So this part works as I said before.

`wget --server-response 192.168.20.20:8081` (yes, this Tomcat really is running under 8081) locally from the loadbalancer responds with 200 and thus works just fine, while trying `wget --server-response admin.mydomain.tech` results in the following:

```
--2018-06-10 20:51:56--  http://admin.mydomain.tech/
Aufl"osen des Hostnamens admin.mydomain.tech (admin.mydomain.tech)... <PUBLIC IP>
Verbindungsaufbau zu admin.mydomain.tech (admin.mydomain.tech)|<PUBLIC IP>|:80 ... verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet ...
  HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html
2018-06-10 20:51:56 FEHLER 503: Service Unavailable.
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something here; I am aware of the differences in forwarding the request as a layer 4 or a layer 7 request – which seems to work just fine. I am providing `mode http` so I am on layer7...

Any hints on what's happening here or on how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my case the `selinux` was the showstopper – after putting it to permissive mode by `setenforce 0`, it just worked...
Since this change is not restart-persistent, I had to follow the instructions found here: https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/